# Probability: balanced die is rolled repeatedly until the same number appears

Tags: probability

> Suppose that a balanced die is rolled repeatedly until the same number appears on the two successive rolls, and let $X$ denote the number of rolls that are required. Determine the value of $Pr(X=x)$, for $x=2,3,\dots$.

I guess the answer is $\big(\frac{5}{6}\big)^{x-2}\big(\frac{1}{6}\big)^2$. Am I right?

Comment: A good sanity check is to see if the probabilities over all $x$ add up to 1.

Comment: Will you please let me know how to check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $X = x$ occurs precisely when:

$\bullet$ The $x-2$ rolls $2,3,\ldots,x-1$ are different from the previous roll.
$\bullet$ The $x$-th roll is the same as the previous roll.

So the probability of this happening is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x-2} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$

Comment: Thanks a lot.I just want to know how the probability of "The x-th roll is the same as the previous roll" is $\frac{1}{6}$?

Comment: Say the $(x-1)$-th roll is a $6$. Then we require the $x$-th roll to be a $6$ as well, which occurs with probability $\frac{1}{6}$. This obviously works no matter what the $x-1$-th roll actually is.