# How to check that probability adds up to $1$

Tags: probability

When I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519693/probability-balanced-die-is-rolled-repeatedly-until-the-same-number-appears/519698?noredirect=1#519698), I got one comment as "A good sanity check is to see if the probabilities over all $x$ add up to $1$."

The right answer to the question I linked is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x-2} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$ and I want to know how it adds up as $x$ goes from $2$ to $\infty$.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us define the sum of the series as $S$ which is,$$S=\frac{1}{6}[1+(\frac{5}{6})+(\frac{5}{6})^2+...].$$ Then multiply both sides by $\cfrac{5}6{}$$$\frac{5}{6}S= \frac{1}{6}[\frac{5}{6}+(\frac{5}{6})^2+(\frac{5}{6})^3+...]$$
Then take the difference of the above two series $$S-\frac{5}{6}S=\frac{1}{6}.$$ Which gives you $S=1.$

Comment: For more . information on series pls see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series

Comment: Many many thanks. Actually,I integrated from $2$ to $\infty$, but forgot that it is not $2\leq x$.

Comment: You are welcome. It is a discreet space, so one should use sums of series.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series):

$$\sum\limits_{x = 2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x - 2} \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{6} \sum\limits_{x = 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^x = \frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{5}{6}} = \frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{6}} = 1$$

as desired. In general, a geometric series can be evaluated by

$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty} a r^k = a \frac{1}{1 - r}$$

provided that $|r| < 1$.

---

In particular, the partial sums can be evaluated as

$$S_N := \sum\limits_{k = 0}^N r^k = \frac{1 - r^{N + 1}}{1 - r}$$

This can be proven by induction, as is done in the linked article.